# Any way to find out whether a MutationObserver is disconnected or observing?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

It appears that [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) shows the full list of methods.

Obviously it's not that difficult to find a way around this... but for the sake of elegance there should be a method `isConnected`, shouldn't there?

Comment: Maybe it would make sense, but it's not in the [specification](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#mutationobserver).

Comment: One potentially guess would be that you can connect an observer to multiple things, so a simple `isConnected` boolean flag wouldn't be that useful.

Comment: @loganfsmyth if you do `disconnect` you disconnect it from everything of course... but of course that is not the whole story, and I understand the point you're making: maybe there should a `getNumberOfObservedTargets` function?... or for that matter `getObservedTargets`... that really would be useful.

Comment: I guess the question is, what are you using this flag for? It can't be used to check "do I need to call .observe" because there could already be observers for other nodes, and using it to check "do I need to call .disconnect" isn't useful because you can just call `.disconnect` to make sure. The number of observers on its own isn't useful, and `getObservedTargets` would potentially expose info that you didn't expect to be exposed. It seems like it comes back to usecase, which you haven't clarified.

Comment: In the past few hours I've completely rethought/re-engineered everything so at the current time I don't need it.  But most listener design patterns are not so secretive.  My biggest beef with `MutationObserver` however is that you can't get a stack trace at the moment when it's triggered... and as the callback is called asynchronously this means you can't find which bit of code caused the DOM mutation.

Comment: All DOM listeners are "secretive" as per specification and don't expose subscribers. In some cases browsers expose the internals via nonstandard methods like `getEventListeners` in devtools console.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks... funnily enough someone made a comment somewhere that you could get a trace to before the MutationObserver was triggered in Chrome using some part of the DevTools... but when I checked I found that this feature has now been removed in the current Chrome versions.  I hate Chrome as it happens but I wish FF would introduce some means of doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If one would really want to know the status of MutationObserver object instance, then a way to get this would be the creation of a new object class from it in a composition style ([JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/SSRRDD/q83fuo6L/18/)):

```
// to keep actual working methods of the class out of the object's instance whenever possible
// is a good practice, but since ECMAScript2015 (ES2015, ES6) does not support private methods
// (though does support private variables with "var" in constructors), IIFE (Immediately-invoked
// function expression) has to be used to encapsulate, isolate the full class definition:
let UpgradedMutationObserver = (function() 
{
        // private variable/property to store the instance's current status; WeakMap is used to improve memory 
        // management as it sheds its value pairs as soon as the instance is not referenced any more:
  const _targetsArrayWeakMap = new WeakMap(), // new WeakMap([[this, []]]) would not work as "this" here is a window object
        // private method-function wrapper that provides access for the object's instance to class prototype
        // methods as well as to an earlier-declared private variable;
        // this wrapper is designed as a function factory as it returns functions that get assigned to the object
        // instance's public methods:
        _callPrototypeMethod = function(prototypeMethod, instance, args)
        {
          // actual type of the private variable/property is set here; runs only once:
          if (typeof _targetsArrayWeakMap.get(instance) === 'undefined')
          {
            _targetsArrayWeakMap.set(instance, []);
          } 
          return function()
          {
            const returnedObject = Object.getPrototypeOf(instance)[prototypeMethod](instance, _targetsArrayWeakMap.get(instance), ...arguments);
            _targetsArrayWeakMap.set(instance, returnedObject.privateVariable);
            return returnedObject.returnValue;
          }
        };
  class UpgradedMutationObserver
  {
    constructor(callback)
    {
      // an arrow function version of the way to attach the object's instance would not need .bind(this)
      // as there is no own "this" in arrow functions, "this" would mean the instance of the object
      this.MutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function( ...args)
      {
        return callback( ...args, this);
      }.bind(this)); 
      this.observe = _callPrototypeMethod('observe', this, arguments); // bind(this);
      this.takeRecords = _callPrototypeMethod('takeRecords', this, arguments); // bind(this);
      this.disconnect = _callPrototypeMethod('disconnect', this, arguments); //.bind(this);
      this.isConnected = _callPrototypeMethod('isConnected', this, arguments); //.bind(this);
      // ... other standard methods like takeRecords() can also taken care of, if necessary
    }
    observe(instance, targetsArray, targetObserve, optionsObserve)
    { 
      // many targets can be observed, though callback function is always the same
      // for the same instance of (Upgraded)MutationObserver:
      instance.MutationObserver.observe(targetObserve, optionsObserve); 
      // before adding targetObserve to the list of observed,
      // it is checked that it exists (at least for now):
      if (document.contains(targetObserve))
      {
        targetsArray.push(targetObserve);
      }
      return {privateVariable: targetsArray};
    }
    takeRecords(instance, targetsArray)
    { 
      // returns a list of all matching DOM changes that have been detected but not yet processed by the observer's callback function, leaving the mutation queue empty      
      return {returnValue: instance.MutationObserver.takeRecords(),
                            privateVariable: targetsArray};
    }
    disconnect(instance, targetsArray)
    { 
      // the method stops observation of all targets at once
      instance.MutationObserver.disconnect();
      targetsArray = [];
      return {privateVariable: targetsArray};
    }
    isConnected(instance, targetsArray, targetToCheck)
    {
      // in case of observed nodes removed from DOM (destroyed), they are filtered out:
      targetsArray = targetsArray.filter(function(e)
      {
        return document.contains(e);
      });
      // maximum versatily of return results is provided 
      // all while maintaining false/"truthy" quasi-boolean dichotomy:
      return {
                privateVariable: targetsArray,
                returnValue: targetsArray.length == 0
                ? false
                : (targetToCheck
                   ? targetsArray.includes(targetToCheck)
                   : targetsArray)
             };
    }
  }
  return UpgradedMutationObserver;
})();  

console.log('UpgradedMutationObserver: ____________________________________________________________');
const observer = new UpgradedMutationObserver(function(mutationsList, observer)
{
  console.log('UpgradedMutationObserver callback: processing of an added node', mutationsList, observer);
});
console.log('UpgradedMutationObserver initialized as "observer": ', observer);
console.log('UpgradedMutationObserver: observer.isConnected(): ', observer.isConnected()); 

console.log('UpgradedMutationObserver: observer.observe(document.documentElement, {childList: true, subtree: true})...'); 
observer.observe(document.documentElement, {childList: true, subtree: true});

// logs "Array [ html....]"
console.log('UpgradedMutationObserver: observer.isConnected(): ', observer.isConnected()); 
  
console.log('UpgradedMutationObserver: observer.observe(document.body, {childList: true, subtree: true})...'); 
observer.observe(document.body, {childList: true, subtree: false});

// logs "Array [ html. ..., body. ...]"
console.log('UpgradedMutationObserver: observer.isConnected(): ', observer.isConnected()); 
  
// logs "true":
console.log('UpgradedMutationObserver: observer.isConnected(document.documentElement): ', observer.isConnected(document.documentElement)); 

var div = document.querySelector('div'), childDiv, i;
for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
  setTimeout(function()
  {
    if (this < 4)
    {
      childDiv = document.createElement('div');
      div.appendChild(childDiv);
      console.log("a child DIV is added after " + this + "s delay for UpgradedMutationObserver to discover");
    }
    else
    {
      console.log('UpgradedMutationObserver: observer.disconnect()...'); 
      observer.disconnect();
      // logs "false" as nothing is observed:
      console.log('UpgradedMutationObserver: observer.isConnected(): ', observer.isConnected(), records); // records value here is an empty array since mutations were already processed in the callback function, provided in the initialization of the UpgradedMutationObserver
    }
  }.bind(i), i * 1000);
}
```

Comment: Impressive.  I haven't currently got the opportunity to check that it operates as I would hope, but thanks for taking the trouble to design this!

Comment: I used a different version of this class to make MutationObserver aware of current mouse coordinates (by attaching an event listener to a new property of a shell class), so it should work. By using this composition style all kinds of peculiar object classes can be created however you like it. The hardest part is making it the first time but after that, it can be amended pretty easily.

Comment: (EDIT: added link to JSFiddle, changed the class structure to make actual working methods belong to the class prototype instead of instances.)

Comment: OMG! Thank you, thank you, thank you! I think you may have just saved my sanity, if not my life.